# Java - Alternative to very long switch case

Tags: java, class, switch-statement

In my Java "Pear" class, I have a huge list of approximately 1000 variables :

```
public class Pear {

    private String 
    a100, 
    a110, 
    a120, 
    ...
    etc.

}
```

I need to set each one of these variables based on the given value of a banana, so I had a first basic idea to do it with a switch case :

```
public class Pear {

    ...

    public void setValues(Banana aBanana) {

        switch (aBanana.getValueName()) {
        case "300886":
            a100 = aBanana.getValue();
            break;

        case "309606":
            a110 = aBanana.getValue();
            break;

        case "300843":
            a120 = aBanana.getValue();
            break;

        /* ...and so on for 1000 variables*/

        }
    }

}
```

, but I feel like this is not the good way to accomplish this, and this is not going to be very readable neither maintainable. How could I replace this switch case ?

Edit : I think there is a misunderstanding on the call of "setValues". It is going to be called like this (I added some pears) :

```
public static void main(String[] bananas) {

    Pear pear = new Pear();

    pear.setValues(bananas[0]);
    pear.setValues(bananas[1]);
    pear.setValues(bananas[2]);
    ...etc for 200 times approximately...

}
```

Comment: Why do you have 1000 aXXX variables to store a `aBanana` object in the first place?

Comment: Learn to use arrays, lists and other data structures

Comment: Create a list of Strings instead of 1000 variables

Comment: _...list of approximately 1000 variables..._ that's very things go south

Comment: You may want to learn about data structures. Namely a Map.

Comment: "I have a huge **list** of approximately 1000 variables" => Use a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) then ! :) What's up with the downvote on the question tho ? He asked a clear question, gave us his code. If you're going to downvote, at least explain why in the comments !

Comment: Create a hashmap<String, String> which would contain key as your value like `300886` and value as variable name.

Comment: Who is upvoting this question?

Comment: @rmlan Why wouldn't we ?

Comment: @AlexandreBeaudet For a few potential reasons: 1. It is arguably an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) 2. It is a "how can I improve my code" question, which is more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AlexandreBeaudet Yes, but a List would not allow me to set the value of each element of the List, would it ...?

Comment: @OttoÉmepé who said that? You can do whatever you like with a list: add new elements, modify existing ones, delete them, add more etc.

Comment: @rmlan Ok, thanks, it is indeed an XY problem, thanks for pointing it, I didn't now the term.

Comment: @OttoÉmepé I would spend a little bit of time learning about the three main collections in Java (List, Set, Map). They are super powerful and very helpful for different use cases. I believe for your case you could benefit from either a list or a map, depending on what type of information you need to store.

Answer (score 2):

Having hundreds of variables to store multiple values of the same kind is room for bugs and difficult maintenance (which led to this question).

If you changed your data structure, you would get rid of all the unnecessary variable declarations, and you would have logic coded against values (codes), rather than variable names.

A **Map** is designed to be used to associate keys to values (value names to values, in your case).

```
Map<String, String> valueMap = new HashMap<>();

public void setValues(Banana aBanana) {
    valueMap.put(aBanana.getValueName(), aBanana.getValue());
}
```

Now this introduces changes elsewhere, but then that's justified because your typical "read" code would start from the same "value names" too:

```
public String getValue(String valueName) {
    return this.valueMap.get(valueName);
}
```

Comment: @Lefteris008 Agreed. "Needing to get rid of huge switch statement" is clearly a sign of a different problem. What would be the point of an answer that keeps everyone in the same, obvious design problem?

Comment: Since you get by key, wouldn't the `getValue()` use getValueName?